# JavaScript to add a class to a div based on XML value

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Hopefully I can explain this correctly. I have some XML on a content block within page (called by a custom CMS). I need to get the value of the one field, which is a numerical price ($999.99), and then instead of display the price outright like that, I need to display it as an image.

The main issue is I can't embed any fonts, and the style of the price needs to be exact, so I'm left with having an image sprite of 0-9, and then creating empty div's awaiting their extra class which will add the background image of the number.

I'm less than thrilled :)

So is it possible to break up the numerical string (I know I can take off the $ and .) and then loop through to add classes to a set of divs (will say the div's all have the ID of "price")? I can figure this out in PHP quite quickly, but being limited to JavaScript, HTML, and CSS, I'm having to think outside the box. Also can only use jQuery version 1.7.2.

The price could have 3-5 digits, so I figure I'd have 5 set divs, then add a "hidden" class if there are only 3 digits in the price.

Thoughts/ideas/suggestions?

---

After pondering some commenters I think it might be easier to add the hidden class by default, then remove it and add the additional class for each number.

Comment: multiple elements should never have the same ID, you could set their class to 'price' instead.

Comment: Can you clarify, maybe show some code and an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: var priceString = "$999.99";

Foreach numerical value (I can do a string replace to remove the $ and .), add a class of that number to the div.

So if it's a number 9, a div class of "nine" needs to be added.

I can lay it out within PHP, but I'm unable to use PHP in this project (unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for (based on your comment): http://jsfiddle.net/Jhmxc/3/

```
$(".price").each( function() {
    var val = $(this).text() 
    $(this).empty();
    for( var i = 0; i < val.length; i++ ) {
        if(/^\d+$/.test(val[i])) {
            $numDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("num"+val[i]);
            $(this).append($numDiv);
        }
        else {
            $(this).append($("<div>"+val[i]+"</div>").addClass("char"));
        }
    }
});
```

i only added classes for 1-3... and those classes only added color, but you can see where i'm going.

**EDIT:**

in regard to your comment below... do this? http://jsfiddle.net/Jhmxc/4/

```
    var val = "$231.2";
    var $output = $("<div></div>");
    for( var i = 0; i < val.length; i++ ) {
        if(/^\d+$/.test(val[i])) {
            $numDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("num"+val[i]);
            $output.append($numDiv);
        }
        else {
            $output.append($("<div>"+val[i]+"</div>").addClass("char"));
        }
    }
    $("#price").append($output);
```

or in a function: http://jsfiddle.net/Jhmxc/5/

Comment: Realizing that doesn't exactly solve my issue, as the data is coming from a variable, not the contents of the div. I just need to alter the div based on the number. I'm trying to switch $(".price") to a variable but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: updated... not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you should be able to work off it

Comment: I was able to get it working based off your update. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, a string is an array, so you can iterate through the characters like this:

```
var priceString = "$999.99";
for( var index in priceString){
    var c = priceString[index];
    //process the character here
}
```

**Edit**
Thanks to the commenters...here's a more cross-browser compatible way to iterate through the characters in a string:

```
var priceString = "$999.99";
for( var index = 0; index < priceString.length; index++ ) {
    var c = priceString.charAt(index);
    //process the character here
}
```

Comment: I'm not great with JavaScript, but you're setting the character to the variable c?

Comment: correct.  Then, if the DIV's area already created, you can reference them using jQuery and set the class.  Something along the lines of `$("#price").get(digitIndex).addClass("className");`  digitIndex is not the same as index, due to the non-numeric characters

Comment: I'm pretty certain IE 7 or 8 and below don't support the array access. To be safe for backwards compatibility, you should use `priceString.charAt(index);`

Comment: Thankfully I only need to support IE 8+, but I'll obviously verify :)